# Create an invalid UTF8 perl string?

Tags: perl, unicode

What's a good way to create a perl string with the UTF8 flag set but contains an invalid UTF8 byte sequence?

Is there a way to set the UTF8 flag on a perl string without performing the native encoding to UTF-X translation (for instance, which happens when you call `utf8::upgrade`)?

I need to do this to track down a possible bug in the DBI driver.

Comment: Unicode and Perl like Bonnie and Clyde - stole your time and grant you a fantastic evening and night :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's exactly what Encode's `_utf8_on` does.

```
use Encode qw( _utf8_on );

my $s = "abc\xC0def";  # String to use as raw buffer content.
utf8::downgrade($s);   # Make sure each char is stored as a byte.
_utf8_on($s);          # Set UTF8 flag.
```

(Never use `_utf8_on` except when you want to generate a bad scalar.)

You can view the damage using

```
use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );
Dump($s);
```

Output:

```
SV = PV(0x24899c) at 0x4a9294
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x24ab04 "abc\300def"\0Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x64, immediately after start byte 0xc0) in subroutine entry at script.pl line 9.
 [UTF8 "abc\x{0}ef"]
  CUR = 7
  LEN = 12
```

Answer (score 8):

You can set an arbitrary sequence of bytes with the UTF8 flag still set by hacking at the guts of a string.

```
use Inline C;
use Devel::Peek;
utf8::upgrade( $str = "" );
Dump($str); 
twiddle($str, "\x{BD}\x{BE}\x{BF}\x{C0}\x{C1}\x{C2}");
Dump($str);
__DATA__
__C__
/** append arbitrary bytes to a Perl scalar **/
void twiddle(SV *s, const char *t)
{
  sv_catpv(s, t);
}
```

Typical output:

```
SV = PV(0x80029bb0) at 0x80072008
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x80155098 ""\0 [UTF8 ""]
  CUR = 0
  LEN = 12
SV = PV(0x80029bb0) at 0x80072008
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x80155098 "\275\276\277\300\301\302"\0Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected continuation byte 0xbd, with no preceding start byte) in subroutine entry at ./invalidUTF.pl line 6.
Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected continuation byte 0xbe, with no preceding start byte) in subroutine entry at ./invalidUTF.pl line 6.
Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected continuation byte 0xbf, with no preceding start byte) in subroutine entry at ./invalidUTF.pl line 6.
Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0xc1, immediately after start byte 0xc0) in subroutine entry at ./invalidUTF.pl line 6.
Malformed UTF-8 character (unexpected non-continuation byte 0x00, immediately after start byte 0xc2) in subroutine entry at ./invalidUTF.pl line 6.
 [UTF8 "\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}\x{0}"]
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 12
```